# How to Join 3 Tables and Count Instances of Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 Tables:

- `Trips` which contains `TripRecordID` and `TripName`
- `TripRecords` which contains `TripRecordID`, `CustID`, and other details for that trip record
- `Customers` which contains `CustID` and customer information

What I would like is a view that lists every single customer with a row for each trip that exists in the `Trip` table and a count of how many trip records exist for that customer for that trip (which could be 0) E.g.

If there are 2 trips and 4 customers, the view would list each customer twice, one for trip 1 and one for trip 2. In each row it would count how many times that customer has a record matching the trip specified. If we add another trip, each customer will get 3 rows and so on.

For example:

[image: Example formatted table]

I'm struggling to write the query. This query returns every customer but not a line for each trip (since not all customers are on all trips):

```
SELECT c.CustID, t.TripID, COUNT (tr.TripID) AS TripCount
FROM dbo.Customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TripRecords tr ON tr.CustID = c.CustID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Trips t ON tr.TripID = t.TripID
GROUP BY c.CustID, t.TripID
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If you provide a [mre] with sample data in addition to desired results, ideally as DDL+DML you make to much easier for people to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your query up from the data your want. So if you want a row per customer, per trip you need a `CROSS JOIN` which gives every combination. Then you can carry out your `LEFT JOIN` to see how many of each combination occured.

```
SELECT c.CustID, t.TripID, COUNT(tr.TripID) AS TripCount
FROM dbo.Customers c
CROSS JOIN dbo.Trips t
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TripRecords tr ON tr.TripID = t.TripID AND tr.CustID = c.CustID
GROUP BY c.CustID, t.TripID
```

Comment: That's awesome! The Cross join was what I needed. The working query needed to be modified a bit but worked awesomely:

SELECT t.TripID, c.CustId, count(tr.TripID) FROM CustID c
CROSS JOIN Trips t
LEFT OUTER JOIN TripRecords tr ON c.CustID = tr.CustID
GROUP BY c.CustID, t.TripID